# change the content of iframe after page load

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, joomla

i am facing a problem for changing the content of `iframe`,
i am working on a website which is developed in joomla using many components
in that i need to combine three components in one.

so i used iframe to load various pages of componeents.

but the problem is when i clicked on link which is in iframe, it load whole page of iframe with header and footer.

see this images
[when page is load with iframe](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ee2afrz45)

[when click on link of iframe](http://awesomescreenshot.com/05d2afsf96)

in this page, click on add entry. it load the whole page with header and footer.
i just only need the content of that component not ehole page.

i tried many things like

**1)**

```
function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
if ( $iframe.length ) {
    $iframe.attr('src',url);   
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

**2)**

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('#someID').html();
```

and many lots things but its not working. because the link wich i want to change is in iframe and when i click on this link of iframe it load the whole page.

so please help me to solve this.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you click an `<a>` tag the IFrame will render the respective link response. Use ajax call on click of any links in IFrame. Extract only body part from ajax response and put it in the respective IFrame body.

Comment: it is joomla's component so how its possible to call ajax on click of any iframe link?

Comment: Iframs are in your project. You have complete control on the content of them.

Comment: but i have not any unique id or class of iframe links. so how can i use onclick function?

Comment: `$('#yourframe a').click()` will do that.

Comment: ok. but when i have to use jquery code? on head or after iframe?
and also let me know, it work only for same domain?

Comment: Ajax works with multy domain communication. Can you show me you code, exactly how are you using ajax. So that I can help further.